# How to replace acronym for some lines of code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, is it possible when i type a acronym, it will replace for some of of code like this:

#### GetAll

will be replace with

#### Descendants("div").Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tool. It allows you to write code snippets using a wizard/
https://github.com/mmanela/SnippetDesigner/wiki/Creating-a-snippet-from-scratch